# Unable to escape the escape quotes when assigning the string to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bash command to run for which I am assigning it to a variable.
The command to be run is:

```
papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{"aviral":"srivastava"}'
```

I am able to print it in python3, as:

```
>>> print("papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{}'".format('{"aviral":"srivastava"}'))
papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{"aviral":"srivastava"}'
```

However, when I assign the same value to the variable:

```
a= "papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{}'".format('{"aviral":"srivastava"}')
```

I get the following:

```
'papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y \'{"aviral":"srivastava"}\''
```

Notice the `\` in the output.

I expect to achieve the desired result(which is done in the `print` statement) using variable assigning.

Comment: could not re-produce . I got `papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{"aviral":"srivastava"}'`  by printing `a`

Comment: Those escapes will only be visible on the REPL. You can safely ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this,

```
>>> print("papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{}'".format('{"aviral":"srivastava"}'))
papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{"aviral":"srivastava"}'
>>> a= "papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{}'".format('{"aviral":"srivastava"}')
```

Here, you are seeing `\` because it is printing a string literal in single quotes.

```
>>> a 
'papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y \'{"aviral":"srivastava"}\''
```

If you print the variable, it will look normal as you required.

```
>>> print(a) 
papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{"aviral":"srivastava"}'
```

Comment: So, I can use the variable ignoring the escape sequences?

Comment: @AviralSrivastava Don't forget to accept the answer, if it cleared your doubts. Happy coding!

Comment: bhaijaan, Is there anything that I should improvise in the question? It got two downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Both strings are exactly the same. You can observe it if you run both commands on an IDE, or via terminal using `python script.py`

```
print("papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{}'".format('{"aviral":"srivastava"}'))
a= "papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{}'".format('{"aviral":"srivastava"}')
print(a)
```

The output will be

```
papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{"aviral":"srivastava"}'
papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{"aviral":"srivastava"}'
```

It's just that Python added an extra backslash around the single quotes because we have double quotes in the string as well, and the backslash escapes the single quotes to provide a printable representation of the string

```
>>> print("papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{}'".format('{"aviral":"srivastava"}'))
papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{"aviral":"srivastava"}'
>>> a= "papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{}'".format('{"aviral":"srivastava"}')
>>> print(a)
papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y '{"aviral":"srivastava"}'
>>> a
'papermill athena-py/params_to_dict.ipynb athena-py/output_params_to_dict.ipynb -y \'{"aviral":"srivastava"}\''
```

Essentially the escaped string is the `repr` representation of the string

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr

> repr(object)
>   Return a string containing a printable representation of an object